Disable automatic S.M.A.R.T. tests
I have a small (single-board) Zimaboard server that is running Debian 12 (bookworm) 24/7 in my bedroom. This server has a single HDD hooked-up, which remains unmounted and in sleep mode except for a daily back-up cycle (after which it is unmounted and goes back to sleep).
Unfortunately, every Monday at 00:45 AM the server decides to wake up the HDD (and myself...) to execute what sounds like a short S.M.A.R.T test. I then have to grab my phone and issue a sleep command to stop the HDD from making its typical HDD noises afterwards (humming, occasional clicks, ...). As you can imagine, this is incredibly annoying, so I want to fix it.
I first looked for crontab schedules (executed as user or root), but I didn't see anything relevant. journalctl --since ... --until ... didn't report anything useful either. The only uncommented line in /etc/smartd.conf says: DEVICESCAN -d removable -n standby -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner. I don't see anything there that could point to a weekly maintenance schedule.
Is there any way to find out what triggered the S.M.A.R.T. test (or similar)? Where do I look for log entries? And how do I prevent it from executing in the middle of the night?

check your logs? try -n standby,q?

@frostschutz I went through journalctl, and I'm not sure where else I would find relevant logs (/var/logs doesn't have a syslog in my case). -n standby,q is not a valid option for journalctl

@MPA -n standby,q is intended to replace -n standby in your DEVICESCAN line in smartd.conf.

I've moved your answer to ... an answer. If you want to add your own (so you get the credit), we can delete the Community Wiki answer and leave yours

This won’t answer your questions about “why” and “where”, but to disable automatic SMART tests, disable the smartd daemon:
sudo systemctl disable --now smartmontools


Thanks, that definitely did something... We'll see on Monday night whether that addressed the issue.

Unfortunately I woke up to HDD noises again last night, so smartmontools was not the culprit. But your solution does what I asked for, so I'll mark it for future visitors

Answer moved from question

After a bit more digging, it turned out not to be a S.M.A.R.T. feature that caused the drive to wake up in the middle of the night. Instead, fstrim was executed weekly attempting to TRIM to any device listed in /etc/fstab that supports it, and by doing so would bring the HDD out of its slumber. Disabling the service (systemctl disable fstrim.timer) solved the issue.
